# Angular 4 permissions management in template and route using route data

Tags: angular, permissions, routes, angular2-routing

I want to add some permissions in my angular apps. I already have my current user permission list when successfully logged in and I save in on local storage.

Here is some example of my permission data

```
{id: 9, name: "configuration.role.restore", display_name: "Restore Role", description: ""}
```

I have searched this and looks like I looks like I can use route.data to solve my problem, but I don't know how to set and use it.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend trying to use [ngx-permissions](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions) library for controlling permissions in your angular application. The benefits it will remove elements from DOM, lazy loading is supported, else then syntax also supported.
Example of loading permissions

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxPermissionsService } from 'ngx-permissions';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private permissionsService: NgxPermissionsService,
               private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const perm = ["ADMIN"];

    this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(perm);

     this.http.get('url').subscribe((permissions) => {
       //const perm = ["ADMIN", "EDITOR"]; example of permissions
       this.permissionsService.loadPermissions(permissions);
    })
  }
}
```

Usage in templates

```
 <ng-template [ngxPermissionsOnly]="['ADMIN']">
     <div>You can see this text congrats</div>
  </ng-template>
    <div *ngxPermissionsOnly="['ADMIN'']">
        <div>Admin will see this</div>
    </div>

  <div *ngxPermissionsExcept="['JOHNY']">
   <div>All will see it except Johny</div>
 </div>
```